# (jzy3d) How to display tool tip on Scatter effectively?

Tags: java, mouseevent, jzy3d

Currently, we are using jzy3d to display data on 3D chart, but we need to display "tool-tips" when mouse button hovers on a point in Scatter data.

Our solution is currently not cpu friendly, since we get all Scatter data with `getProjection` method, and iterate over returned array to find matched boundary with mouse point.

Do you know or recommend better and fast way to display tool-tips on scatters`s data?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I would start by setting the points in a quad map to minimize the number of point to check. I however don't know how efficient is the quad map index phase, and it is maybe not a good idea if your user remain free to rotate the scene whenever he wants.

Comment: You can also look at the org.jzy3d.picking package that makes use of GL_SELECT. Basically, it ask for rendering in a very small region around the mouse pointer, and you then read a buffer to see what was actually drawn. The graph demo will help you to understand how that works.